# How to make a video element in an Android Webview play unmuted

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I have an Android WebView that houses a Advertisement that is a video which is Auto-Played once the website is loaded. Because of Chromes Limitation AutoPlayed Videos are automatically set to Muted.

So all of this to say is there a way around the AndroidWeView to get  the autoplayed video to follow the users device settings instread of defaulting to muted? Is it possible to access the DOM of the HTML and click the button that way? I appreciate all responses.

I have tried to use a different WebView Browser like Mozillas GeckoView but Mozilla also has the same enforcement.

I've read around and people said to use
`settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = true`
but this does not unmute the sound.